# An old-fashioned way of reading the time

Tags: time

My elderly grandmother, before she passed away, had a very distinct way of reading the time. It has been quite some time since she passed away and I can't quite remember the exact phrasing she used when telling the time. I have searched google but unfortunately all I can find is old methods for telling the time, which isn't quite relevant (and she certainly wasn't that old).

As best as I can remember, her way of reading the time was something like this; for example if the time was 5:45 or 6:28.

> 'Five and forty past the five',

or

> 'Eight and twenty past the six'.

Is anyone familiar with this way of expressing the time and can give me more information on it?

Comment: What side of the Atlantic was your grandmother from?

Comment: It sounds like the style of “four and twenty blackbirds”.

Comment: There was a discussion about two-digit number ordering in general (not just times) in a [previous question on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3903/19th-century-english-texts-occasionally-use-germanic-style-number-words-such-as).  The short version is that Old English used to use German-style ordering ("four-and-twenty"), but has gradually transitioned to French-style ordering ("twenty-four").

Comment: My mother born 1920, London, died 1966, (and her brothers and sisters born 1910 onwards) used to say 'five-and twenty' to (or past) (an hour 1 to 12) for HH:25 and HH:35 times. Only these.